# Linq "Select" Sanity Question

Tags: c#, linq

I have logic similar to the code below. It seems as though in order to check for null references like this, I have to have two separate Select statements. Could a linq ninja tell me in which way a query like this could be improved?

```
List<C> cList = Globals.GetReferences(irrelevantThing) // GetReferences returns List<A>, which are references to B
            .Select(a => a.GetB()) // GetB returns type B, can be null
            .Where(b => b != null && someOtherConditions)
            .Select(c => new C(b)) // C Constructor cannot have a null parameter
            .ToList();
```

Thank you.

EDIT: Cleaned up example code a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it slightly better looking with the query syntax and the `let` operator:

```
   var queryB = from a in Globals.GetReferences(irrelevantThing)
                let b = a.GetB()
                where b != null && someOtherConditions
                select new B(b);

   var bList = queryB.ToList()
```

Depends on your preferences though...

FYI in extension method syntax, the above translates to

```
   var queryB = Globals.GetReferences(irrelevantThing)
            .Select(a => new { a, b = a.GetB() })
            .Where(x => x.b != null && someOtherConditions)
            .Select(x => new B(x.b))
            .ToList();
```

UPDATE: just realized that you can also use the `select into` clause to translate the exact original query literally :

```
   var queryB = from a in Globals.GetReferences(irrelevantThing)
                select a.GetB() into b
                where b != null && someOtherConditions
                select new B(b);
```

still prefer `let` though...

Comment: Though I bow in deference to @jonskeet, I believe this answers my question quite well. I agree that the query syntax looks much nicer in this scenario.

Comment: added another possibility using `select into`

Answer (score 5):

Well, for one thing I'd change the parameter names - after the first `Select`, you've got a B, so why not call it `b`?

```
List<B> bList = Globals.GetReferences(irrelevantThing)
            .Select(a => a.GetB()) // GetB returns type B, can be null
            .Where(b => b != null && someOtherConditions)
            .Select(b => new B(b))
            .ToList();
```

At that point, I have to wonder why you've got the second `Select` at all... you've already got a B, so why are you creating a new one? What does the `B(B old)` constructor do?

If you *do* need the other select though, that seems okay to me. I mean, if `GetB` is cheap, you could always use:

```
List<B> bList = Globals.GetReferences(irrelevantThing)
            .Where(a => a.GetB() != null && someOtherConditions)
            .Select(a => new B(a.GetB()))
            .ToList();
```

... but I'm not sure I would, to be honest.

Comment: I changed the example slightly- it was a little off. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Jon. Personally, I'd use the "where first" method provided that GetB is cheap. I don't know that there's any difference in execution, since Linq statements are compiled and optimized anyway, but it looks cleaner to my eyes.

Comment: @raynjamin: Okay, in that case I think it's fine as it is.

Comment: @Ryan: The execution will depend on what kind of LINQ provider is involved. Given that the OP talks about a `List<T>`, it'll be LINQ to Objects - so with the extra Select, there'll be one extra layer involved in each iteration.